# How to get number of groups in a groupby object in koalas?

Tags: python, databricks, spark-koalas

How to get number of groups in a `groupby` object in `koalas` ?

In pandas we can use `ngroups`, but this method is not implemented yet in koalas.

Suppose `groupby` object is called `dfgroup`.

Any idea ?

Comment: maybe try `len(dfgroup)`... I'd try it myself but from some reason I'm unable to install koalas.

Comment: It doesn't work : `object of type 'DataFrameGroupBy' has no len()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to force execution of some function on that [GroupBy object](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/groupby.html) (type: `databricks.koalas.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy`), and from that you can get a length.  For example, the `dfgroup.size()` will return `databricks.koalas.series.Series` on which you can call `len` (example is adapted from documentation):

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby(['Animal'])
>>> type(grouped.size())
<class 'databricks.koalas.series.Series'>
>>> len(grouped.size())
2
```

Answer (score 0):

in koalas

```
df1.groupby('School').first().pipe(len)
```